# How to add attribute to a renderized td in GridView?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I'm using an ASP.NET GridView.
Inside it, I have a TemplateField as follows:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nº Despesa" SortExpression="NumeroDespesa">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID='lblNumeroDespesa' runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("NumeroDespesa") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv-col-numerodespesa" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass="gv-col-numerodespesa text-center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This code gets rendered in the client as:

```
<td class="gv-col-numerodespesa text-center">
    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder_Site_gvDespesa_lblNumeroDespesa_0">00403-03-01</span>
</td>
```

I'd like to add a data-title on the td, like this:

```
<td class="gv-col-numerodespesa text-center" data-title="Nº Despesa">
    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder_Site_gvDespesa_lblNumeroDespesa_0">00403-03-01</span>
</td>
```

How can I achieve it?

My final objective with this is to implement [NoMoreTables](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way, but you probably won't like it. I don't, anyway.

You can subscribe to RowDataBound event and in the handler set attributes of the cell. You need to know the index of the column though. Assuming index 3:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[3].Attributes.Add("data-title", "Nº Despesa");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Using the Cells collection is the last resort, I want to avoid doing it as much as possible.

Comment: @Lucas, yep, i agree, hence "won't like it" remark. There is no other server-side way really. Only js approaches, and I am not sure those are any better

Comment: Not even some hack to be put on PreRender? Like the one used to make GridView render thead and tfoot separately?

Comment: Sigh... I'll try to make a generic method to get the cell header and put it in a foreach then... It's sad that we can't just throw the attribute on the itemstyle, like we can do with labels and textboxes.

Comment: @Lucas, well, at least I do not know such way. Just thought of one more though: you could also inherit template field and make it understand Attributes.

Comment: @Lucas, yeah, iterating on columns for needed header is perhaps a bit safer than index, agreed on that